# How can i get duplicate node CYPHER Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a question How can i I get some nodes with same property (for example same name property). In SQL i would use GROUP BY, but in CYPHER i don't have idea what should i use to group them. Below I added my simple input and example output to visualizate my problem.

```json
[
  {
    id:1,
    name: 'name1'
  },
  {
    id:2,
    name: 'name2'
  },
  {
    id:3,
    name: 'name2'
  },
  {
    id:4,
    name: 'name3'
  },
  {
    id:5,
    name: 'name3'
  },
  {
    id:6,
    name: 'name3'
  },
  {
    id:7,
    name: 'name4'
  },
  {
    id:8,
    name: 'name5'
  },
  {
    id:9,
    name: 'name6'
  },
  {
    id:10,
    name: 'name6'
  }
 ]
```

My solution should gave me this:

```
[
  {
    count:2,
    name: 'name2'
  },
  {
    count:3,
    name: 'name3'
  },
  {
    count:2,
    name: 'name6'
  }
]
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

In Cypher, when you aggregate (for the straight-forward cases) the grouping key is formed from the non-aggregation terms.

If nodes have already been created from the input (let's say they're using the label :Entry), then we can get the output you want with this:

```
MATCH (e:Entry)
RETURN e.name as name, count(e) as count
```

The grouping key here is `name`, which becomes distinct as the result of the aggregation. The result is a row for each distinct `name` value and the count of nodes with that name.